# How can I use a condition 'and' condition in a script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to check if both conditions return the expected values.
I want to be sure that both return the expected value before continuing...
My problematic line is: `if [ [ $ansmob = "y" ] || [ $flagbook != "1" ] ];`

```
read -r -p "Would you like to add $site.booking.local as well? [y/n] " ansbook
        if [ $ansbook = "y" ];
                then sed "s/ServerAlias.*/& $site.booking.local/" -i $workdir/$site$dom.conf
                flagbook="1"
        fi
read -r -p "Would you like to add m.$site.booking.local? [y/n] " ansmob
        if [ [ $ansmob = "y" ] || [ $flagbook != "1" ] ];
                then sed "s/& $site.booking.local/& $site.booking.local m.$site.booking.local/" -i $workdir/$site$dom.conf
                else
                sed "s/ServerAlias.* /& m.$site.booking.local/" -i $workdir/$site$dom.conf
                flagmobile="1"
        fi
```

Comment: Can you please show me a usage example?

Comment: You can't nest single brackets, just do `[[ $ansmob == "y" || $flagbook != "1" ]]`

Comment: Ok, i know that, so what is the right way?

Comment: What do you mean? Using an and operator `[[ $ansmob == "y" && $flagbook == "1" ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary && operator is the syntax for the AND operation.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if [ [ $ansmob = "y" ] || [ $flagbook != "1" ] ];
```

with

```
if [ "$ansmob" = "y" ] || [ "$flagbook" != "1" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

with bash's double brackets, you can use `&&` and `||`

```
if [[ $ansmob = "y" || $flagbook -ne 1 ]]
```

Within double brackets, it's not strictly necessary to quote the variables: this command is smart about evaluating expressions with empty variables.